# How to avoid using Sub query & optimize below mentioned query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing, subquery

```
    ---------------------------------- Lead MASTER TABLE
Create table leads
(
    pk_lead_id int primary key identity,
    lead_name varchar(50),
    lead_mobile varchar(50)
)


insert into leads
        select 'AK','9876543210'
insert into leads
        select 'AK1','9876543210'
--....
insert into leads
        select 'AK1000','9876543210'

----------------------------------Lead TRANSACTION TABLE

Create table lead_tr
(
    pk_leadtr_id int primary key identity,
    fk_lead_id int,
    tr_date datetime,
    tr_remarks varchar(500)
)

--- For Lead ID 1
insert into lead_tr select 1,GETDATE(),'This is First Transaction'
insert into lead_tr select 1,GETDATE(),'This is Second Transaction'
--...
insert into lead_tr select 1,GETDATE(),'This is Hundredth Transaction'

--- For Lead ID 1000
insert into lead_tr select 2,GETDATE(),'This is First Transaction'
insert into lead_tr select 2,GETDATE(),'This is Second Transaction'
---...
insert into lead_tr select 2,GETDATE(),'This is Hundredth Transaction'

------------------- MY PROC. for Lead Details With Latest STATUS


select * from leads
left join
    (
        select fk_lead_id,max(pk_leadtr_id) as pk_leadtr_id from lead_tr
        group by fk_lead_id
    )as ltmin on ltmin.fk_lead_id = pk_lead_id
left join lead_tr as lt on lt.pk_leadtr_id = ltmin.pk_leadtr_id
```

I have leads table contain lacs of records.
And transaction table will contain 50 transactions for each row of leads.
How can I avoid sub query?How to ptimize this SP.
Do i need to change my table sturcture for this?

Comment: i) why are using left join ?ii) why you will always need so many record at a time. iii)From @GarethD 's queries check which one is faster.Then Create index view of that query.then you can easily use view in proc and pass other parameter. iv)I think outer apply has to be fast .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Gary Walker's logic of APPLY being the best way to do this, however I don't agree with the application. I think your query should be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Leads L
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    Lead_tr tr 
            WHERE   tr.fk_lead_id = l.pk_lead_id
            ORDER BY tr.pk_leadtr_id DESC
        ) tr;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c9a2/5)**

This allows you to get all columns from `Lead_tr` without having to join to it again.

You can also do this using the ROW_NUMBER() function, this has fewer logical reads on your sample, but consistently executes slower than when using APPLY when I have tested it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Leads L
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tr.fk_lead_id ORDER BY tr.pk_leadtr_id DESC)
            FROM    Lead_tr tr
        ) tr
            ON tr.fk_lead_id = l.pk_lead_id
            AND tr.RowNum = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2c9a2/6)**

---

### Comparing Performance

**APPLY**

> (3 row(s) affected)
>
> Table 'lead_tr'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'leads'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 48 ms.

**ROW_NUMBER**

> (3 row(s) affected)
>
> Table 'lead_tr'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'leads'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 146 ms.

*N.B Both queries run on a warm cache so compile time is 0ms for both so not included above.*

On your actual data you may get different results though, so as always, test on *your* data and chose the method that works fastest for you.

Comment: In Left join Scan count 10, logical reads 394 & execution time is 4 second.After using outer apply Scan count 36466, logical reads 117088 & execution time is 3 seconds. So what is good as per performance?

Comment: IO is just one metric for performance, you also need to look at what the actual execution plan is doing, and CPU performance. The most significant metric though is time, if one query consistently executes significantly faster than another (in fair tests), I would always opt for this one, rather than worrying about any of the other metrics

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an index to lead_tr on fk_lead_id

Recommend you try cross apply

E.g., you can probably use something similar to this

```
select L.*, XL.*
from Leads L
cross apply (
    select max(pk_leadtr_id) as tr_id
           from lead_tr TR
           where TR.fk_lead_id = L.pk_lead_id
    ) XL
```

Cross Apply is pretty much always the fastest method in my experience

There are plenty of cross apply tutorials on the web, there is also outer apply (which corresponds to outer join)

Answer (score 0):

Mathese F, how can you sugest to use union all, union all, union all repeated "row count" times to insert some temp... and then some triggers? please...

Please do not use any of his suggestions. Try to use window function instead to select most recent child rows.

```
;WITH temp 
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tr.fk_lead_id ORDER BY tr.pk_leadtr_id DESC) AS marker, 
                * 
         FROM   leads AS s 
                LEFT JOIN lead_tr AS tr 
                       ON tr.fk_lead_id = s.pk_lead_id ) 
SELECT * 
FROM   temp 
WHERE  temp.marker = 1 
        OR temp.marker IS NULL 
ORDER  BY pk_lead_id
```

Read more on window functions [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/) or anywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

I would first recommand to use union instead of this.

For example :

```
insert into leads
select 'AK','9876543210'
union
select 'AK1','9876543210'
union
select 'AK1000','9876543210'
```

It will cost to sql one operation instead of a lots.

Where these values are coming from?

Then you could imagine to have a trigger, it will have the small benefits of creating a transaction. And applies even if not in the sp.

Is the 50 fixed? How are they created?

Could you imagine to make a join between the first table here upper and another one to insert them?

At least you will always have 2 insert (perhaps with an output clause it could be nice)

**UPDATE**

Here is an example with an output :

```
declare @test table (i int)
declare @test2 table (i int, dada date )

insert into @test 
output inserted.*, GETDATE() into @test2
values (1)

select * from @test
select * from @test2
```

My execution plan only show one query instead of 2 so i think it's better if possible.

Comment: I think you have missed the point of the question. The OP is asking about the select query at the bottom of the code. The inserts were just to provide the DDL to assist with this.

Comment: oups yes in fact !( Thanks